# Getting the insert and update ID with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Im trying to get the `mysql_insert_id` using PDO.
Thus far i've not found a good example that works with both inserting and updating.
Does anyone have a piece of complete code as example?

Comment: You realize that the value you get from mysql_insert_id is the same before and after a sql `UPDATE`, correct?

Comment: Do you not see what's wrong in this post? You're trying to use **mysql_** insert_id using **PDO**

Comment: there's no way to get the id of the row that was updated without an additional SELECT statement when using INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Comment: - NathanielFord The ID is not the where argument i'm updating on, thats why i'd like the ID back

- Truth I know that, i used that word to explain what I needed back

@SosialLab thanks for that!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you *need* `$pdo->lastInsertId()` to return the id of the row just updated (I would seriously reconsider my design if I needed it but hey... can be a true need), do the update like this:

```
 UPDATE tablename  SET some_column='somevalue',id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id);
```

Comment: you're absolutely right about the design part, unfortunatily at this point I dont see another solution

Comment: You got me thinking and yes I didn't really need this :P

Answer (score 3):

[PDO::lastInsertId](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php). Returns the ID of the last inserted row or sequence value

Comment: Thanks Kristianto, the last inserted row I can get back, the updated ID I can't get back. Do you have a peice of example code perhaps?
I might be doing something wrong, used the code from php.net

Comment: How you get ID before updated? ID of the last updated row is the same ID that you use to find & update that row. Last insert = AUTO_INCREMENT but the last updated ID not.

Comment: Actually I do un update query on a "WHERE `name` = 'bla' ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT 1" and i'd like to get the ID it updated.

Comment: Add new column called `on_update`. After updated, call with `ORDER BY on_update`

Comment: You're right that's probably the best solution. thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
try { 
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'usrname', 'passwrd'); 

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO test (name, email) VALUES(?,?);"); 

    try { 
        $dbh->beginTransaction(); 
        $stmt->execute( array('user', 'user@example.com')); 
        $dbh->commit(); 
        print $dbh->lastInsertId(); 
    } catch(PDOExecption $e) { 
        $dbh->rollback(); 
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>"; 
    } 
} catch(PDOExecption $e) { 
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "</br>"; 
} 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, that seems to work. only for UPDATE's it doenst return an ID, is that not possible with PDO?